# How to setup this data structure efficiently?

Tags: function-construction, data-structures, associations

```
d["apple"] = {1, 2, 3};
s["apple"] = 1;
d["banana"] = {10, 20, 30};
s["banana"] = 10;
d["kiwi"] = {100, 200, 300};
s["kiwi"] = 100;
data = {"apple", "banana", "kiwi"};

myfun["model1"][data_, scale_] := Total[data];
myfun["model2"][data_, scale_] := Total[data]/scale;
myfun["model3"][data_, scale_] := Exp[Total[Log[data]]];
```

The main function that runs:

```
mymain[data_, scale_, model_] := Block[{answer},
  answer = myfun[model][data, scale]
];
```

Say then I make some calls to `mymain`

```
mymain[d["apple"], s["apple"], "model1"]
mymain[d["banana"], s["banana"], "model1"]
mymain[d["apple"], s["apple"], "model2"]
mymain[d["banana"], s["banana"], "model3"]
mymain[d["kiwi"], s["kiwi"], "model3"]
```

How do I edit the code in `mymain`, so that I have a *track of record* of what has been done. Say I want to have a look, what have been fitted to `model1`, I would get the result from running

```
mymain[d["apple"], s["apple"], "model1"]
mymain[d["banana"], s["banana"], "model1"]
```

I wonder if possible to have a global variable, say `result`, that can store all the information. So that when I call `result["model1"]`, it gives me the two quantities I described above.

AND if I want to know, what models have been fitted to the "kiwi" data, I call `result["kiwi"]`, would only get the result from

```
mymain[d["kiwi"], s["kiwi"], "model3"]
```

If I *then* do

```
mymain[d["kiwi"], s["kiwi"], "model1"]
```

and `result["kiwi"]` would give me the results from

```
mymain[d["kiwi"], s["kiwi"], "model1"]
mymain[d["kiwi"], s["kiwi"], "model3"]
```

Each call to `mymain`, the result is stored in `result`. So I can extract them for later use.

Comment: I do not follow your application of `Block`.  What is it intended to do?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That was just a random example. My actual `mymain` does a lot computations and there will be some local variables.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that a somewhat different structure will ultimately benefit you, and I shall attempt to recommend one if and when I better understand your needs.  However for the moment these examples might be useful to you:

```
data = {"apple", "banana", "kiwi"};
models = {"model1", "model2", "model3"};

result[m_List][par_] := result[#][par] & /@ m

result[m_][par_List] := result[m] /@ par
```

Now:

```
result[models]["banana"]

result["model1"][data]

result[models][data]
```

> ```
> {60, 6, 6000}
>
> {6, 60, 600}
>
> {{6, 60, 600}, {6, 6, 6}, {6, 6000, 6000000}}
> ```

Comment: I went through your example, which runs fine. Sorry if I was not clear. But I hope to keep the `current` structure of the main function `mymain`. What I am looking for is a way to *store* the results from running the function `mymain`. After running some particular calls to `mymain`, I want to be able to extract the results.

Comment: I have updated my question, hope that is now more specific.

Comment: @Chen I just looked at your update.  I am not sure I understand.  You wish to update `result` (or is `res` different?) ever time `mymain` is used?  Is `result` not used directly?  If you could give an example of the actual input you would ideally like to use and the output or effect that you would like it to have it will help me.

Comment: really sorry for not being able to explain myself clearly. Please see updated post again. Thanks.